# Im having trouble with the IF function, below is the formula info that I was given to use, do I need to use the =if(and...) formula?

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

In cell H2, create a function to add the text Gold Customer if the Rental Period is 9, and Insurance Coverage is Yes. If the condition is not met the cell should be blank.

this is one of my attempts which i know is wrong: IF(E3=9 F3=yes, "gold customer", "")
i am quite new to these functions and this one stumped me.

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: what would you the formula look like because its showing that i have too much information entered

Comment: You're missing the `AND` portion.

Comment: i added in one of the formulas i tried to use, but i know its incorrect

Comment: =if(and(e2=9,f2=yes,"gold customer", ""))   someone told me to use this but this didnt work

Comment: The position of the parentheses matters: `IF(AND(E2=9,f2="Yes"),...)`

Comment: =IF(AND(E2=9,F2="yes"),"Gold Customer","") i typed in this and looks  like it worked

Comment: More important than it working is that you understand *why* it works :-)